# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted

Tags: python, django, csrf, django-csrf, requestcontext

I try to build a very simple website where one can add data into sqlite3 database. I have a POST form with two text input.

index.html:

```
{% if top_list %}
    <ul>
    <b><pre>Name    Total steps</pre></b>
    {% for t in top_list %}
        <pre>{{t.name}} {{t.total_steps}}</pre>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% else %}
    <p>No data available.</p>
{% endif %}
<br>
<form action="/steps_count/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    Name: <input type="text" name="Name" /><br />
    Steps: <input type="text" name="Steps" /><br />
   <input type="submit" value="Add" />
 </form>
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from steps_count.models import Top_List

class Top_List_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Top_List
```

views.py:

```
# Create your views here.
from django.template import Context, loader
from django.http import HttpResponse
from steps_count.models import Top_List
from steps_count.forms import Top_List_Form
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response

def index(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    #form = Top_List_Form(request.POST)
    print "Do something"
else:
    top_list = Top_List.objects.all().order_by('total_steps').reverse()
    t = loader.get_template('steps_count/index.html')
    c = Context({'top_list': top_list,})
    #output = ''.join([(t.name+'\t'+str(t.total_steps)+'\n') for t in top_list])
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

However, when I click the "submit" button, I get the 403 error:

```
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
```

I have included `{% csrf_token %}` in index.html. However, if it is a RequestContext problem, I really have NO idea on where and how to use it. I want everything to happen on the same page (index.html).

Comment: Also make sure your browser accept cookies.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the [`render` shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) which adds `RequestContext` automatically.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from steps_count.models import Top_List
from steps_count.forms import Top_List_Form


def index(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        #form = Top_List_Form(request.POST)
        return HttpResponse("Do something") # methods must return HttpResponse
    else:
        top_list = Top_List.objects.all().order_by('total_steps').reverse()
        #output = ''.join([(t.name+'\t'+str(t.total_steps)+'\n') for t in top_list])
        return render(request,'steps_count/index.html',{'top_list': top_list})
```

Answer (score 21):

You may have missed adding the following to your form:

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

Answer (score 16):

**add it to the setting file**

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'https://appname.herokuapp.com'
]
```

Comment: clear, easy and simple

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 9):

When you found this type of message , it means CSRF token missing or incorrect. So you have two choices.

1. For POST forms, you need to ensure:

   - Your browser is accepting cookies.
   - In the template, there is a {% csrf_token %} template tag inside each POST form that targets an internal URL.
2. The other simple way is  just commented one line (**NOT RECOMMENDED**)('django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware') in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES from setting tab.

   ```
   MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
       'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
       'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
       # 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
       'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
       'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
       'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
       'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
   ```

   )

Comment: Thanks for second part. I simply do not need that! :)

Comment: Turning CSRF off is *NOT* a solution. Please don't do that. (part 2 of the answer)

Answer (score 6):

One more nicest alternative way to fix this is to use `'@csrf_exempt'` annotation.

With `Django 3.1.1` you could just use `@csrf_exempt` on your method.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
```

and you don't need to specify `{% csrf_token %}` in your html.

happy learning..

Comment: It is `from django.views.csrf.decorators import csrf_exempt` instead of `from django.views.decorators import csrf_exempt`

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me with Django 3.1.1 but you need to                  from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

Answer (score 3):

A common mistake here is using render_to_response (this is commonly used in older tutorials), which doesn't automatically include RequestContext.  Render does automatically include it.

Learned this when creating a new app while following a tutorial and CSRF wasn't working for pages in the new app.

Answer (score 2):

In your HTML header, add

```
<meta name="csrf_token" content="{{ csrf_token }}">
```

Then in your JS/angular config:

```
app.config(function($httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = $('meta[name=csrf_token]').attr('content');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using DRF you will need to add `@api_view(['POST'])`

Answer (score 0):

```
function yourFunctionName(data_1,data_2){
        context = {}
        context['id'] = data_1
        context['Valid'] = data_2
        $.ajax({
            beforeSend:function(xhr, settings) {
                    function getCookie(name) {
                            var cookieValue = null;
                            if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                                var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                                for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                                    var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            return cookieValue;
                        }
                        if (settings.url == "your-url")
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
                    },

            url: "your-url",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(context),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json'
        }).done(function( data ) {
    });
```

Comment: You should wrote your ajax like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you put `{%csrf_token%}` and still you have the same issue, please try to change your angular version. This worked for me. Initially I faced this issue while using angular 1.4.x version. After I degraded it into angular 1.2.8, my problem was fixed. Don't forget to add angular-cookies.js and put this on your js file.
If you using post request.

```
app.run(function($http, $cookies) {
    console.log($cookies.csrftoken);
    $http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies.csrftoken;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1) {% csrf_token %} is not in template 
                 -- or --
2) {% csrf_token %} is outside of html-form

Comment: This almost8 years old question clearly describes `I really have NO idea on where and how to use it`. So how is this an answer?

Comment: @Elijan9 1) sometime  {% csrf_token %} not used in html-form then used othervise 2) we used  {% csrf_token %} in template but they have some error is given that time you check that line in  out of html-form

Answer (score 0):

USE decorator:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def method_name():
    # body
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your browser is accepting cookies. I faced the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="/steps_count/" method="post">
 {% csrf_token %}
 Name: <input type="text" name="Name" /><br />
 Steps: <input type="text" name="Steps" /><br />
 <input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
```

Check your alignment it should be one space inside the form. That's where almost everyone makes mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Because I did not set [csrf_token](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#std-templatetag-csrf_token) tag in `<form></form>` with `method="post"` as shown below:

```html
<form action="{% url 'account:login' %}" method="post">
  {% comment %} {% csrf_token %} {% endcomment %}
  ...
</form>
```

So, I set `csrf_token` tag in `<form></form>` with `method="post"` as shown below, then the error was solved:

```html
<form action="{% url 'account:login' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  ...
</form>
```

In addition, whether or not you set `csrf_token` tag in `<form></form>` with `method="get"` as shown below, then there is no error. *only `get` and `post` request methods can be set to `method` for `<form></form>` but not `head`, `put` and so on according to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054165/using-put-method-in-html-form#8054241):

```html
<form action="{% url 'account:login' %}" method="get">
  {% comment %} {% csrf_token %} {% endcomment %}
  ...
</form>
```

```html
<form action="{% url 'account:login' %}" method="get">
  {% csrf_token %}
  ...
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

CSRF(Cross-Site-Request-Forgery) helps in preventing attacks on a web application or a website.
Each session in Django has it's own token and when a session expires the token is destroyed and you have to request for new tokens to access a session.In my case my session had ended and I was logged out of my session.I had to create a new superuser and log in again.

Comment: One thing I want to add on this error that you encountered is that the solution applies differently to other errors you encounter.Like my case I had all the requirements including the `{% csrf_token %}` and the rest of the files were in order but kept on getting the same error.Sometimes it's the minor details that matter.In this case I had to create a new superuser and refresh to get new tokens.I hope this clear and if it's not I'll be more than glad to help with where I can.