# Django tinymce safe template tag

Tags: python, django, django-tinymce

I'm currently trying django tinymce, I want to show on the main page a truncated text of around 200 characters in total.

The problem is that I don't want html tags to show up nor images to show up in this truncated text.. Is there an easy way to solve it?

Example:
If an image is in between the 200 characters, the img tag, attribute and so on will show up and if i used the safe template tag, the image will be rendered. How should I solve this issue? should I write my own template tag and remove the images?

Second problem is that I couldn't find the option to browse images from the user PC and upload it. I don't want any page to view the media, I only want to browse and upload images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Django includes a template tag `striptags` to strip html tags. It uses regular expressions, it's not the right solution but it'll do the job.

2) It seems, browsing images is not included as an option in `django-tinymce`. You need to use another module and integrate it with TinyMCE to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [django-multiuploader](https://github.com/garmoncheg/django_multiuploader) to upload images. I had nice experience with it.

Comment: It cannot be included within tinymce. I want it to be an option in tinymce.

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13985552/django-with-jquery-tinymce-image-upload-plugin

and http://justboil.me/