# Django CSRF token authentication failing

Tags: python, django, csrf

I'm trying to write a webpage that allows user to input an "Idea" and save it to the database. I want to use the Post method of the form. I tried following the instructions on the [django page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it), but the authentication still fails.

This is my form code:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %} 
   <p> Title: </p>  <input type="text" name="title"> </br>  
   <p> Details: </p> <input type="text" name="details"> 
   <input type="submit" value="Post"> 
</form>
```

My URLconf redirects `/` to `Ideas.views.home` with the line

```
url(r'^$', 'Ideas.views.home' , name='home')
```

The view itself is

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader, Template, Context, RequestContext   
from django.core.context_processors import csrf 
from Ideas.models import Idea 


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        submitted = Idea.objects.create(title=request.POST['title'], detail=request.POST['details'], votes=0) 
        submitted.save()
    m = RequestContext(request, {"passed_ideas": Idea.objects.all()})
    return render_to_response('basic.html', m)
```

I have also tried doing this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader, Template, Context, RequestContext   
from django.core.context_processors import csrf 
from Ideas.models import Idea 


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    c = {} 
    c.update(csrf(request)) 
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        submitted = Idea.objects.create(title=request.POST['title'], detail=request.POST['details'], votes=0) 
        submitted.save()
    c['passed_ideas'] = Idea.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('basic.html', c)
```

How do I get the CSRF authentication to work?

Comment: try @csrf_exempt decorator to your view, this eliminates csrf token validation, if it works, you can dig more...

Comment: @MartinM Thanks, at least I can continue development for now!

Comment: no problem, take a look at klasske's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to use render, or you have to add crsf to the render to response like so:

```
render_to_response('basic.html', add_csrf(request, ***other context***))


from django.core.context_processors import csrf
def add_csrf(request, ** kwargs):
   """Add CSRF and user to dictionary."""
   d = dict(user=request.user, ** kwargs)
   d.update(csrf(request))
   return d
```

Not that I like this option, but this is how I did it. I think the RequestContext is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a few weeks back. It seems that redirecting to the url with '/' causes it to drop the CSRF token. If that is the problem, add trailing_slash=False to your router:

```
# urls.py
router = DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)

urlpatterns = patterns('', 
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='home'),
    #all of your urls go here
)
```

This will eliminate the redirect, and the CSRF token should come through.

Comment: sorry, i'm a Django n00b. Is that in the settings.py file?

Comment: for mine, its in the urls.py. It looks like this: router = DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False) urlpatterns = patterns('', ...)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` when you render your template in order to process your csrf token

```
 return render_to_response('basic.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: is that when i'm using the second code i put up (with c.update(crsf(request)))

Comment: Yes, and you can remove `c.update(csrf(request))` from that one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone who helped, but switching from

```
return render_to_response(...)
```

to

```
return render(request, ...)
```

finally fixed it

Comment: after this, I found a similar (although not the exact same) post here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388033/csrf-verification-failed-request-aborted?rq=1