# Do Browsers support PUT requests with multipart/form data

Tags: javascript, html, forms, rest

When I submit this form from Google Chrome, the browser makes a GET request. Are HTTP PUT requests submitted from HTML forms generally unsupported client-side?

```
<form id="#main-form" action="http://localhost:8080/resource/1" method="put"
            enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 12):

The HTML markup language only support GET and POST requests, but you can make the other requests (PUT,DELETE,etc) with Ajax.

There are already answered questions about this:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/114156/why-there-are-no-put-and-delete-methods-in-html-forms

[Why don't browsers support PUT and DELETE requests and when will they?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805956/why-dont-browsers-support-put-and-delete-reqests-and-when-will-they)