# How should I call the Servlet doPut() method using JSP form with HTTP method PUT

Tags: html, jsp, servlets, http-put

I googled up and got the the following result:
[Using PUT method in HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054165/using-put-method-in-html-form)

Now I did this by following way:

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String method = req.getMethod();
        if (method.equals("GET")) {
            this.doDelete(req, resp);
        }
    }
```

Is there any other way to call the `doPut()` method without overriding in the `service()` method?

I have a list of products. Now I want to update the product details using the servlet `doPut()` method by using JSP form with the HTTP method, `PUT`.

This is my JSP form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/book/update" method="post">
</form>
```

Comment: In servlets it is not available.

Comment: You're confusing "Servlets" with "HTML". Moreover, if Servlet didn't support it, then e.g. JAX-RS couldn't exist.