# Angular ng-file-upload method PUT not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload for handle my uploading file.

But i got problem when i'm using method: "PUT".

```
  Upload.upload({
      url: APIROOT + 'categories/' + $routeParams.id,
      data: data,
      method: 'PUT'
  }).then(function (response) {
       ResultService(response.data);
   }, function (response) {
       ResultService(response.data);
   }).finally(function () {
       $scope.loading = false;
       $scope.button_text = "Update";
   });
```

my API Code just simply (laravel 5.1) :

```
   dd($request->all());
```

At my server i can't receive the data. But if i change method to "POST" i can receive it properly.

Any solution?

Comment: Can you show us your api code?

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe Hi, i've update my question above with the api code.

Comment: Are you getting an error code?

Comment: No error. I just got nothing. I've tried both route resource and manually make the route.

Comment: Older browsers (read: IE < 10) don't support `PUT`, that may be an issue. Have you checked if the data is actually sent to the server?

Comment: It looks like your issue is more related to laravel than to angular. Your above code works great with a .Net back-end.

Comment: @zeroflagL im using latest chrome. I know put is work because i've tried using put updating data.

Comment: @Deblaton Jean-Philippe yeah seems like it. Looks like I'll just use post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue related to "laravel". You are not able to receive the data which has been sent using "PUT" method because "ngFileUpload" module internally uses "Form" to upload image with or without data and Form supports only two methods "POST" & "GET".

Please refer the following link for more clarification...
[Using PUT method in HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054165/using-put-method-in-html-form)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

extend data form with `{_method: 'PUT'}` so Laravel will detect it want PUT method.