# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218 Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have to access to PUT route via browser and get json object, but L5.2 show me an MethodNotAllowedHttpException error what have I do to for fix this ?

My URL http://laravel5.restapi.dev/a?_method=put

My route:list

route.php

```
<?php

Route::put('/a', function () {
   return view('welcome');
});
```

Output

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:
in RouteCollection.php line 218
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('PUT')) in RouteCollection.php line 205
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('PUT')) in RouteCollection.php line 158
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 821
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Debugbar.php line 49
at Debugbar->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Debugbar), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Comment: Your route has a `PSOT` declaration. You say you're using `PUT`, that's enough to understand a "Method Not Allowed". But, when you say `accessing via browser`, what do you mean? Direct URL access via browsers can only make a `GET`.

Comment: wait....you want `PUT`, you define `POST` in code, and expect it to handle `PUT`? I don't understand.

Comment: @PeteHouston Sorry for error I define Route::put not Route::post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PUT method works only when your Form Method is POST and then you add _method input field with value PUT.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
</form>
```

Comment: It also works if your form method is PUT, in browsers that support it.

Comment: @ceejayoz yes .. but It was only supported in Mozilla firefox. And as given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054165/using-put-method-in-html-form "XHTML 1.x forms only support GET and POST. GET and POST are the only allowed values for the "method" attribute."

Comment: @jaysingkar Is there any recipe to do same but with Form Method GET ?

Comment: Yes.. but its not a standard method... what you can do is get the `_method` parameter in your using `$_GET['_method']` and check if its PUT

Comment: could you tell me the reason for using get ? as, it it not recommended

Comment: @jaysingkar I finally find what I need. I want have method spoofing not only in POST request but in GET either . Damn (

Comment: @SamvelBudumyan GET requests should never be destructive. PUT/PATCH/DELETE should have to use POST if you're using method spoofing.

Answer (score 1):

The PUT-request is not allowed since you're using `Route::post($uri, $callback)`.

You need to specify your route as `Route::put($uri, $callback)` or (if you need to match other requests, too):

```
Route::match(['post', 'put'], '/a', function () {
    // for post & put requests
});

Route::any('/a', function () {
    // for all methods
});
```

As said in the comments and in the other answer, PUT-requests must be POST-requests with the additional parameter `_method=PUT`.

Please refer to: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#basic-routing

Comment: Ok I see , Im sorry .  In my task I have to be able have access to PUT route via browser What I must to do ?

Answer (score 0):

you can also use

```
    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
```

inside your form with method = post . so that method_field converts it to put

Then in your routes.php

```
     Route::put(.....);
```

or

```
    Route::any(...);
```