# Changing HTML/Express.js setup from POST to PUT?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-post, multipartform-data, http-put

I have a function that works perfectly fine but I realized I'm using a POST function when it's probably proper to use PUT.

I switched `app.post('/word', docType, function (req. res) {` to `app.put`

Then in the html I switched:

```
<form action="/mediaDev/word" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

to: `method="put"`

After making this change I end up getting `502 Bad Gateway`.

Is there a crucial difference between POST and PUT that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you inspected the actual request being made? It is probably a GET.

See ["Using PUT method in HTML form"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054165/using-put-method-in-html-form) for more information...

> According to the HTML standard, you can not. The only valid values for the method attribute are get and post, corresponding to the GET and POST HTTP methods. `<form method="put">` is invalid HTML and will be treated like `<form>`, i.e. send a GET request.

EDIT: On second thought I'm not certain why this would mean you get a 502 Bad Gateway, however I will leave this answer as I believe it is still useful.

Comment: Interesting, it's not possible to use PUT from html. This is disappointing, I'll have to find a work around.

Comment: Well my express application was only listening for PUT requests and ignoring GET. So makes sense to me. Looks like what I want to do is just more trouble than it's worth. (I did see a workaround in your link, but not worth the effort)