# Can't use PUT method with flask

Tags: python, flask, put

*I wrote this easy program:*

```
@app.route('/puttest/', methods=['GET', 'PUT'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        return 'Hello, {}!'.format(request.form['name'])
    else:
        return '''
            <title>Does it work ?</title>
            <h1>PUT test</h1>
            <form action=http://localhost:8887/puttest/ method=put>
                <input type=text name=name>
                <input type=submit value=try>
            </form>

        '''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', 8887)
```

It works perfectly for `GET` method, but it doesn't work with `PUT`. Trying to send `put` message, I can see this error at a browser:

```
Method Not Allowed

The method is not allowed for the requested URL.
```

***What has happened to `put` method ?***

*It will work fine if I change `put` method on `post` everywhere in program.*

Comment: Maybe you have one Slash too much. Try http://localhost:8887/puttest in form and /puttest in route

Comment: @Nils no, it works with `post` correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PUT won't work with HTML method attribute.
Allowed values are: method = get|post

You have to use POST in Webforms:

```
@app.route('/puttest/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
if request.method == 'POST':
    return 'Hello, {}!'.format(request.form['name'])
else:
    return '''
        <title>Does it work ?</title>
        <h1>PUT test</h1>
        <form action=http://localhost:8887/puttest/ method=post>
            <input type=text name=name>
            <input type=submit value=try>
        </form>
    '''
```

Further informations at: [Using PUT method in HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054165/using-put-method-in-html-form) and [HTML Standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-method)