# Route [dashboard.update] not defined. while it is defined in routes (routs/web.php) file

Tags: php, laravel, routes

This is my code of laravel routes file and all other routs working nicely but 'update' route giving an error that 'Route [dashboard.update] not defined'
here is code of routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'prefix' => 'dashboard'],function (){

// get routes
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('dashboard.index');
Route::get('add', 'HomeController@addNotice')->name('dashboard.add');
Route::get('{id}/edit', 'HomeController@editNotice')->name('dashboard.edit');
Route::get('{id}', 'HomeController@showNotice')->name('dashboard.show');

// post routes
Route::post('add', 'HomeController@storeNotice')->name('dashboard.store');
Route::post('{id}','HomeController@updateNotice')->name('dashboard.update'); //error here
Route::post('{id}', 'HomeController@deleteNotice ')->name('dashboard.delete');
});
```

here is the code of view return by HomeController

```
<form action="{{ route('dashboard.update',['noticeId' => $noticeId->id]) }}" method="POST" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="noticeTitle" placeholder="Give Title to Notice" value="{{ $noticeId->title }}">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea name="noticeBody" cols="30" rows="8" class="form-control" placeholder="Add Notice Details Here" style="resize: none">{{ $noticeId->body }}</textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" name="editNotice" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-info btn-block btn-sm">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Thank you @FPJ and it really helps, I was using post method for update and delete while they have 'put' and 'delete' methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Route::post('{id}','HomeController@updateNotice')->name('dashboard.update');
```

to

```
Route::put('{id}','HomeController@updateNotice')->name('dashboard.update');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your route type to `PUT` or `PATCH`

```
Route::patch('{id}','HomeController@updateNotice')->name('dashboard.update');
```

And this to your form

```
{!! method_field('PATCH') !!}
```

The error here is because your delete route is overwriting the update route since they're of the same type and path. Typically for delete routes you should use the 'DELETE' method.

Comment: you can not patch/put using forms!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054165/using-put-method-in-html-form

Comment: `The method_field function generates an HTML hidden input field containing the spoofed value of the form's HTTP verb.`, so this will conflict with `Route::patch`

Comment: this is just a work around, and will not perform a patch request

Comment: @hassan That's how laravel forms and routes work. Thanks for the downvote.

Comment: yes I was using 'post' method for both 'update' and 'delete'. but after changing to 'put' and 'delete' now its working