# Why submitting form with PUT method I got GET request?

Tags: laravel-5

In my laravel 5.7 app I make form for updating of data, like:

```
<section class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title">Edit vote</h4>


    <form method="PUT" action="{{ url('/admin/votes/update/'.$vote->id) }}" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="form_vote_edit" class="form-horizontal"
          enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {!! csrf_field() !!}
        <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
```

with routes dined in routes/web.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'isVerified', 'CheckUserStatus'], 'prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {
    ...
    Route::put('/votes/update/{vote_id}', 'Admin\VotesController@update');
```

but submitting the form I got request with error:

```
Request URL: http://local-votes.com/admin/votes/update/22?_token=0CEQg05W4jLWtpF3xB6BGSdz1icwysiDOStLVgHv&id=22&name=gg...
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
```

Why GET request, what is wrong in my form ?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using PUT method in HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054165/using-put-method-in-html-form)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML Forms only support `GET` and `POST`.

From the docs:

> Since HTML forms can't make PUT, PATCH, or DELETE requests, you will
>   need to add a hidden  _method field to spoof these HTTP verbs.

You can use the [method_field](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-method-field) helper or the [@method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#method-field) blade directive to add the hidden input.

```html
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    @method('PUT')
    ...
</form>
```

or

```html
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
    ...
</form>
```