# How to send PUT request inside same project from form using PHP

Tags: php, http, post, request, put

I want to send `PUT` request inside same project to different page from form using `PHP`. 
How can i check request? is it `POST` or `PUT`?

my code

```
<form method="POST" action="request.php"> 
    <input type="text" name="name" value="blahblah">
    <button type="submit">UPDATE</button>
</form>

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        //
    }
```

Thanks, regards

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054165/using-put-method-in-html-form

Comment: `According to the HTML standard, you can not. The only valid values for the method attribute are get and post, corresponding to the GET and POST HTTP methods. <form method="put"> is invalid HTML and will be treated like <form>, i.e. send a GET request.`

Comment: as I understand it, i will add into form input element and it's attribute name will be "_method". Also  i will manual check like this if($_POST['_method'] == 'PUT').

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using PUT method in HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054165/using-put-method-in-html-form)

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, as mentionned, forms only accept sending via GET or POST. To send data with the method PUT, You can do it in AJAX (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ with JQuery). Unfortunately, you will most probably have to do some work with the page that is receiving the form as you will probably want to return XML or JSON instead of HTML.

Here below a very basic example just to show is at work. You should see the request method (PUT) in your Javascript console.

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT') {
    echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
}

else {

?>


<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: '/test.php',
                method: 'put',
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            }
        );
    })
</script>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Also, when i send request via jquery ajax, can i check via $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT'; for response ?

Comment: You can indeed.