# Overriding http methods in fastify

Tags: html, node.js, forms, webmethod, fastify

I am creating a CRUD app in node with fastify and TypeScript. How can I override rest methods in html forms?

For example in the Html:

```
<form action="/removeproduct" method="DELETE">
   <input type="text" name="productname" />
</form>
```

And in the node fastify code:

```
app.delete('/removeproduct', (request, reply) => {
  // code to remove a product from db
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using PUT method in HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054165/using-put-method-in-html-form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't in this way since the standard define that you can use GET and POST only: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

To archive that you should call a javascript function on submit in the html page. Then write your own ajax call using `fetch`. In this way you will be able to declare all the methods in the REST API standard