# How to use Url.Action to get to the controller and also generate the url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, url, routes

When using this button

```
<a onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Update", "Book", new { id = @Model.Id })'"
               class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
```

The controller indeed hits the get method

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{id}")]
public ActionResult Update(int id) {...}
```

But the Url is not anymore matching the route {controller}/{action}, it just shows the id like this

> https://localhost:44345/1

Answer (score 2):

You are overriding the entire route when you use the [Route()] attribute on your endpoint, this is why the controller name portion is removed. I imagine the reason you have done this is due to a conflict with an existing **GET** action.

You appear to be using a **GET** request to update your entity. Instead use **POST** or **PUT** depending on the scenario (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) and update your **HttpGet** attribute accodingly.

```
[HttpPost]
// or
[HttpPut]
```

However, XHTML 1.x forms only support **GET** and **POST** as HTTP request methods. You can either use **POST** or you can see workaround [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8054241/9328542) if you want to use **PUT**.

Also, ensure that you have a route attribute on your controller class that looks like this:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class BookController : ControllerBase
```

This will ensure that the controller portion of the route is included, so the format will be: *.../{controllerName}/{id}*

**NOTE:** If you want to stick with **GET** and have multiple requests of the same HTTP message type then you can route to the correct action by updating the [HttpGet] attribute rather than adding a [Route] attribute :

```
[HttpGet("update/{id}")]
```

This will give your url the following format *.../{controllerName}/update/{id}*

Comment: there's no <form method="put">

Comment: HTML forms currently only support GET and POST as HTTP request methods. You can either use POST or you can see workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8054241/9328542 if you want to use PUT

Answer (score 0):

you can use an ancor helper

```
<a asp-action="Update" asp-controller="Book" asp-route-id="@Model.Id" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Route` attribute, it will override the route template.

So if you use ASP.NET Core MVC, you need use the route template like below:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Your Controller should be:

```
public class BookController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Update(int id) {

        return View();
    }
}
```

Then the Url.Action should work as expected:`https://localhost:44345/Book/Update/1`

```
 <a onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Update", "Book", new { id = @Model.Id })'"
           class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
```

---

If you use ASP.NET Core WebApi, controller should be like below:

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class BookController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id}")]
    public ActionResult Update(int id) => Ok();
}
```