# Error on trying to override POST method with PUT (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, overriding, koa

I am experiencing a "Method Not Allowed" issue when trying to override my POST request with PUT (for updating information in my blog). I already installed method override for koa.

HTML:

```
  <div class="create-message content">
<form action="/messages/edit/<%= message.id %>?_method=PUT" method="POST">
  <label for="title">Message title:</label>
  <input required value="<%= message.title %>" type="text" id="title" name="title" required>
  <label for="snippet">Message snippet:</label>
  <input required value="<%= message.snippet %>" type="text" id="snippet" name="snippet" required>
  <label for="body">Message body:</label>
  <input required value="<%= message.body %>" type="text" id="body" name="body" required>
  <button>Update</button>
</form>
```

My routs are the following:

```
  //edit message
  router.get('/messages/edit/:id', async (ctx, next) => {
    const id = ctx.params.id;
    const result = await MessageModel.findById(id)
    await  ctx.render('edit', {
      title: 'Messages',  
      message: result
     })
    });
```

The code above runs well, but after I click on submit button, "Method Not Allowed" issue occurs instead of running this:

```
  //update edited message
  router.put('/messages/edit/:id', async (ctx, next) => {
      MessageModel.findByIdAndUpdate(ctx.params.id, ctx.request.body, {new:true}, (err:any, result:any) => {
      })
    return ctx.redirect('/');
});
```

Please share your thoughts on this issue.
Thank you

Comment: Did you add this line `app.use(methodOverride('_method'))`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the following to your app.js (index.js) file.

```
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
```

Comment: That was the issue, thanks for saving me hours!)

Answer (score -1):

You [can't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8054241/4935162) set the form method to PUT, it's either GET or POST.

to send a PUT request you can use AJAX, via (for instance) the [Fetch API](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2021/09/20/fetch-http-put-request-examples)

EDIT: my bad, you used the "tunneling" concept mentioned in that solution.

per [this](https://github.com/expressjs/method-override) documentation, maybe try with

```
<form method="POST" action="/resource" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"> 
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```