# Form DELETE method is redirecting to the GET method instead in EXPRESS JS

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a form here with the delete method being used:

```
<form action="/article/<%= articles[i]._id %>" method="DELETE"><button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button></form>
```

Then my routes for the article ID's look like this:

```
const articleById = require('../controllers/article/articleById')
router.get('/:id', articleById)

const deleteArticleById = require('../controllers/article/deleteArticleById')
router.delete('/:id', authLoggedIn, deleteArticleById)
```

The form should be using the router.delete with its controller but instead it is using the router.get and using that controller instead. I verified this by using console.log in each controller and when I submit that form it will send me to router.get instead. I'm not sure how to get the form to use the router.delete.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using PUT method in HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054165/using-put-method-in-html-form)

Comment: From the duplicate, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65630961/283366) for the server side and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8054241/283366) for the client side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML Form doesn't support PUT, PATCH, DELETE method. Form only support GET and POST method. Thats why method="DELETE" is not working and instead it calls GET.

But you can override this behaviour using method-override package.
http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/method-override.html

```js
var express = require('express')
var methodOverride = require('method-override')
var app = express()

// override with POST having ?_method=DELETE
app.use(methodOverride('_method'))
```

```html
<!-- HTML Form using DELETE -->
<form method="POST" action="/resource?_method=DELETE">
  <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Why `/resource`? Why not use the actual URL in OP's question?

Comment: Awesome, that worked perfectly. Always thought that DELETE was a standard html thing that could be used in forms. Maybe I just got that idea from CRUD or something?

Comment: @DeveloperLewis modern forms still not supporting other methods. You can use fetch also to perform delete here. `fetch('/resource', {method: "DELETE"}).then(res => res.json()).then(data => console.log(data))`

Comment: @Phil I was trying make the solution more generic. I am a new here in terms of answering and I don't know much about rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="/article/<%= articles[i]._id %>" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button></form>
```

**Try This Way **

Comment: Won't OP also need the [method override middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/method-override.html)?